# Using Ansible, is there a way to pull another docker image if the docker pull throws a 404 error?

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-image

I want to implement a solution where if one docker image can not be pulled due to it not existing, then another one is pulled instead.

```
 - name: Pull an image
   docker_image:
     name: repository:stable
   with_list: "{{ repository }}"
```

For example, usually, if an image with the tag `stable` does not exist a `404 Client Error: Not Found` is thrown, is there a way to catch this error and pull repository:latest instead? Or a possible workaround to achieve pulling the second, if the first does not exist?

I am also using this to pull many docker images, from a list of repositories.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can probably `register` the output of the `docker_image` task and then try to figure out what went wrong, possibly running a second `docker_image` task (with a `when` condition). Ansible does not have this functionality out of the box, but you can probably emulate it using multiple tasks.

Comment: Thanks @nwinkler I will try to implement your solution. Although it doesn't appear to be working straight away, as after adding the `register` the playbook still fails out with the 404 Client Error.

Comment: You can change the failure behavior - please see here for examples: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html Using a mixture of `ignore_errors` and `failed_when`, you should be able to control when it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying issue was that the error message returned from the `block` consists of a dict of arrays.  Where each array corresponds to the error dict of that execution.

Therefore I couldn’t use `in`, as this was searching for an exact match value on the property, but the property was nested in an array. Fortunately there was another Boolean property on the parent object that provided me with the information, so I used the `failed` key instead.  `failed` is true when the docker image pull failed.

```
- block:
   - name: Pull an image
   docker_image:
     name: repository:stable
   with_list: "{{ repositories }}"
   loop_control:
     loop_var: repository
rescue:
  - name: Pull latest-dev image
    docker_image:
      name: repository:latest
    when: ansible_failed_result.failed
    with_list: "{{ repositories }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: repository
```

The main line is `ansible_failed_result.failed` which refers to an element in the dict which has `Failed: true`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an error handling `block` to catch this situation and if your using Ansible 2.1+ the new `ansible_failed_result` variable will make it easier to inspect the result of the failed task too.

I would try something like this if you need to take multiple task action on a failure:

```
- block
    - name: Pull an image
      docker_image:
        name: repository:stable
      with_list: "{{ repository }}"
  rescue:
    - name: Do some etc parsing to determine the issue
      set_fact:
        pull_latest: '{{ "404" in ansible_failed_result }}'
    - name: Pull second image
      docker_image:
        name: repository:latest
      when: pull_latest
```

Comment: does this solution require ansible_failed_result to be set as the outcome of the first task? Currently, I have a flow where the Pull an image Fails, with `404 Client Error: Not Found` however, in the set_fact step, it is not setting pull_latest to true as `"pull_latest": false}, "changed": false`, then Pull Second Image results in: `"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"`

Comment: @fuzzi Try to set a debug output of what your getting in the `ansible_failed_result` variable in the rescue section. I just sudo coded the set_fact task in my example depending on what is in the variable you may have to tweak how you set the `pull_latest` var. You should not need to set the value of the `ansible_failed_result` yourself it is automatic if the task errors.

Comment: I upvoted your answer as this was great advice to get to the correct answer, however I could not get this working to catch the error, and I posted an answer to explain why.